# How can I find out if a UIColor is pattern-based?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

Suppose I want to set the background image for a `UIView`; apparently I do this by calling `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage]`. Is there any way to determine if a `UIColor` object has been initialized in this way, i.e., if it is a *pattern* rather than a solid color?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Answer (score 5):

You could try calling `CGColorGetPattern(color.CGColor)`. This function doesn't document what happens if the color is not a pattern color, but it's reasonable to expect that it will return `NULL`,

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would try:

```
if (CGColorGetPattern(uiColor.CGColor)) {
    // it's a pattern-based color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift, you can use following extensions:

```swift
public extension UIColor {

  /// Returns `true` if the color is backed by patterned image.
  var isPatterned: Bool {
    cgColor.pattern != nil
  }
}
```

Also for AppKit `NSColor`, you can do:

```swift
public extension NSColor {

  /// Returns `true` if the color is backed by patterned image.
  var isPatterned: Bool {
    type == .pattern
  }
}
```